# Keyerror "batchsize"

Tags: python, linux

```
2022-09-26 17:12:58 - ### Training ###
2022-09-26 17:12:58 - Creating a new model in 
2022-09-26 17:12:59 - BertImgModel Image Dimension: 2054
2022-09-26 17:13:00 - Use pytorch device: cuda
2022-09-26 17:13:00 - Flickr30k Image Feature Split exists. Loading from /home/fq1312/MMT/DATAset/split_folder
2022-09-26 17:13:00 - Start to load Faster-RCNN detected objects from /home/fq1312/MMT/DATAset/split_folder/train_flickr30k_resnet101_faster_rcnn_genome.tsv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_train_test.py", line 278, in <module>
    run(config)
  File "run_train_test.py", line 64, in run
    task.get("batchsize", train_config["batch_size"]))
KeyError: 'batch_size'
```

```py
def run(config):
    if "seed" in config:
        torch.manual_seed(config["seed"])               # Sets the (CPU) seed for generating random numbers and returns a torch.Generator object.
        np.random.seed(config["seed"])
        random.seed(config["seed"])
    model_config = config["model"]
    model_folder_name = f"{model_config['name']}-{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M')}"
    model_save_path = os.path.join(config["model_path"], model_folder_name)
    os.makedirs(model_save_path, exist_ok=True)

    if config.get("use_wandb", False):
        wandb_config = config["wandb"]
        run = wandb.init(config=config, project=wandb_config.get("wandb_project", "mmt-retrieval"), name=wandb_config.get("wandb_name", model_folder_name), reinit=True)
    logging.info(config)
    if config.get("do_train", True):
        logging.info("### Training ###")
        logging.info("Creating a new model in ", model_save_path)

        model = build_model(model_config)

        if config.get("use_wandb", False):
            wandb.watch(model)

        train_config = config["training"]
        training_tasks = []
        dataset_callback = None
        for task in train_config["tasks"]:
            dataset = DATA_LOADER[task["name"]](get_data(config["data"], task["name"]), "train", task.get("tiny", True), model.image_dict,
                                                joint=task["loss"]["name"] == "joint", **task.get("data_args", {}))
            sampler, batch_sampler, shuffle, batch_size = get_sampler(task["name"], dataset,
                                                                      task.get("batchsize", train_config["batch_size"]))
            dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, shuffle=shuffle, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=sampler,
                                    batch_sampler=batch_sampler, num_workers=train_config.get("num_workers", 0))
```

this is the config:
#Enable training
do_train: Train
training:
tasks:
# Train Cross Encoder with Cross Entropy
- name: flickr30k # Alternative: mscoco, multi30k; selects the training dataset
tiny: false
batchsize: 128    # ## primary test: 128
loss:
name: joint
data_args:
jit_loading: False   # True for just-in-time loading of image features from disk. Recommended for little RAM. Combine with num_workers to mitigate slowdown
languages: [en, de, cs, fr ] # ONLY multi30k, select the languages
dev:
tasks:
# Evaluate Cross Encoder for Image-Text Retrieval
- name: flickr30k # Alternative: mscoco, multi30k
tiny: true # Recommended. Use a smaller dev set because Cross Encoder is slow
evaluator:
name: ce_itr
data_args:
captions_per_image: 1 # Recommended. Use only one caption per image because Cross Encoder is slow
languages: [en] #, de, cs, fr ] # ONLY multi30k, select the language. ONLY 1 Language at once for eval. Repeat this task for each language to evaluate all languages
batchsize: 512   # ## primary task: 512
main_score_function: mean
use_amp: True # Automatix Mixed Precision during Training
epochs: 1
steps_per_epoch: 100000 # Remove to run each epoch in full  100000
evaluation_steps: 5000 # Evaluation after each epoch and after this number of steps  5000
warmup_steps: 0.0 # As a fraction of the total steps
lr: 0.00005
weight_decay: 0.05
max_grad_norm: 1
gradient_accumulation: 1
num_workers: 0 # Number of workers for DataLoader. 0 to disable
do_dev_test: False # Use test config but use dev split
do_test: True # Test on test split
test:
tasks:
# Evaluate Cross Encoder for Image-Text Retrieval
- name: flickr30k # Alternative: mscoco, multi30k
tiny: false
evaluator:
name: ce_itr
data_args:
languages: [en] #, de, cs, fr ] # ONLY multi30k, select the language. ONLY 1 Language at once for eval. Repeat this task for each language to evaluate all languages
batchsize: 512  # ## primary test: 512

Comment: the problem lies outside the code you have provided. ``config["training"]["batch_size"]`` doesn't exit in the config which gets passed into the ``run(config)``.

Comment: #Enable training
do_train: Train
training:
  tasks:
    # Train Cross Encoder with Cross Entropy
    - name: flickr30k # Alternative: mscoco, multi30k; selects the training dataset
      tiny: false
      batchsize: 128    # ## primary test: 128
      loss:
        name: joint
      data_args:
        jit_loading: False   # True for just-in-time loading of image features from disk. Recommended for little RAM. Combine with num_workers to mitigate slowdown
        languages: [en, de, cs, fr ] # ONLY multi30k, select the languages